# skin spark flash button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I tried to change classic spark button image with my own custom image. For this I used skinsClass property of the button.
My problem is when I click on the button for a short time my image appears and deappears an then the action for the button is executed.
I want to achive something like a static image click.

This is the code for the button:

```
var button:Button = new Button();   
button.setStyle('skinClass', skins.ImageButtonSkin);
```

This is the code for the skin class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        minWidth="48" minHeight="48"
        alpha.up="1"
        alpha.down="0">
    <!-- host component -->
    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <!-- states -->
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="disabled" />
        <s:State name="down"  />
        <s:State name="over" />
        <s:State name="up" />
    </s:states>

    <s:BitmapImage source="../assets/gift-icon.png" includeIn="down"/>
    <s:BitmapImage source="../assets/gift-icon.png" includeIn="up"/>
    <s:BitmapImage source="../assets/gift-icon.png" includeIn="over"/>
    <s:BitmapImage source="../assets/gift-icon.png" includeIn="disabled"/>
    <!-- SkinParts
    name=iconDisplay, type=spark.primitives.BitmapImage, required=false
    name=labelDisplay, type=spark.core.IDisplayText, required=false
    -->
</s:Skin>
```

Answer (score 1):

To overcome this issue i used instead of s:Button an s:Image with the property buttonMode="true"

Answer (score 0):

alpha.down="0" -> alpha.down="1"